# Using colors as words

Tags: creative-writing, poetry, metaphor, figures-of-speech

> He was clad with white and silver bracelets.

Can we use colors such as white and use them as a substitute for other words like "white clothes"?

> He was clad with white linen and silver bracelets.

I am thinking since we use material such as linen to substitute for other words like clothes, we could do the same with colors, but I am not sure.

Comment: In this particular example (the first one), it sounds to me like the bracelets are white and silver, so if that's not what you mean it should probably be rephrased

Comment: I would say "hey was clad in white [clothes] and in silver bracelets" to disambiguate from the possibility of white+silver bracelets.

Comment: Yes, "white and silver bracelets" is easily misunderstood. Try "He was clad in white and adorned with silver" or "shone with silver" or "wore bracelets of silver"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is done already. Consider: He strode onto the pitch in freshly pressed whites. (Cricket)

'He was clothed in brown rags' doesn't mean he was actually wearing rags.

It is quite common to say something like: He was clad in white and silver.

Consider: She was resplendent in crimson and yellow.

Comment: +1 Good points. I've never thought of it like that before.

Comment: You said *in* four times and you never said *with* once. That part's kinda important.

Comment: @Mazura: In this context, "with" does not sound quite right. "In" is usual, so saying "clothed with" sound stilted. Might be appropriate when writing high fantasy mock-Arthurian, but you have to be very careful that you know what you're doing.